# how to join a laravel relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to write a sort class for spatie query builder but my problem is I have 3 models `hotel` `room` and `discount` so now hotel has many rooms and rooms has many discounts I want to sort the hotels by the lowest discount available on rooms so now here is the query I tried note that `$query` is loading all the hotels:

```
$data = $query->with('accommodationRoom')
            ->join('discounts','accommodation_rooms.id','=','discounts.accommodation_room_id')
            ->get();
```

but I get this error :

> message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accommodation_rooms.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `accommodations` inner join `discounts` on `accommodation_rooms`.`id` = `discounts`.`accommodation_room_id` where exists (select * from `accommodation_rooms` where `accommodations`.`id` = `accommodation_rooms`.`accommodation_id` and `bed_count` = 5))",

its because I am loading a relation to a join but that does not recognizing the filed.

Comment: `with` is a sub-query, not a join. You'll have to either join all 3 tables together, or pass the join as a closure on your `with`.

Comment: @aynber how that is possible to join 3 tables ?

Comment: Just use multiple join statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple join statements..

```
    $data = DB::table('accommodation_rooms')
       ->join('hotels','accommodation_rooms.id','=','hotels.room_id') // replace room_id with your column name
       ->join('discounts','accommodation_rooms.id','=','discounts.accommodation_room_id')
       ->select('accommodation_rooms.*','hotels.*','discounts.*')
       ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Relation in Model files.

**Hotel Model**

```
Class Hotel{

    public function room()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class,'hotel_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Room Model**

```
Class Room{

    public function discount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Discount::class,'room_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Record Fetch Query**

```
$data = Hotel::with('room', 'room.discount')->orderBy('room.discount.value', 'ASC')->get();
```

***Change your model and field name in the above code.***

Answer (score 0):

You should join with `accommodationRoom` too.

You can even join to multiple tables in a single query:

```
$data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms','hotels.id','=','accommodation_rooms.hotel_id')
    ->join('discounts','accommodation_rooms.id','=','discounts.accommodation_room_id')
    ->select('hotels.*', 'discounts.*')
    ->orderBy('discounts.value')
    ->get();
```

See [Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins).

Comment: @Farshad check it out.

Comment: i dont know why i get empty array though i have the relation between them existing i am sure .

Comment: Did you check the additional `join` and ther `orderBy` that I put? I am not sure that the attributes are correct.